# How to resolve the RStudio Server Crashing in EC2

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, random-forest, rstudio-server

I just finished configuring RStudio Server in the EC2 instances.

At the moment, I am trying to run the RandomForest model in the server. The training table has about 100,000 instances and 150 features.

At first, I used an instance of `m4.large` instance with 16GB Memory, and I used the command of top to monitor the rsession. When the VIRT is over 16GB, RStudio gave me an error message:

> The previous R session was abnormally terminated due to an unexpected crash. You may have lost workspace data as a result of this crash

So I resized the instance to `m4.2xlarge`, then it crashed again while reaching 32GB.

Now I'm confused why this happens, I don't want to always resize the instance to handle a bigger job. And I'm afraid this might be too costly for me in the future. So I am wondering if there is any good solution way for this.

Thanks

Comment: Are any of the features factors (categorical)?

Comment: There is only one factor attribute, and it only has 7 levels. Do you think this is a problem?

Comment: I wouldn't think 7 levels would be a problem.

Comment: I used train() method from caret package to build the model, today I tried with randomForest() from randomForest package directly, it could work. So I am wondering is there is anything different in caret's train method.

Comment: Caret does automatic hyper-parameter tuning, I believe it does this by a grid search by default. This could likely be why it consumes more resources.